# Set maxconnections from client(ip)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

Today we received hundreds of request at the same time, same url and same ip.
Which lead to our database crashed. (It was a bug in our app)

Is it possible to allow max 2 connections / sec / ip. Where is the best way to do this?

We use Azure to run the page and the database. The page runs on 3 instances on Azure. The page is built in ASP.NET.

Comment: I don't believe this is going to be a code question. This is likely configuration you need to make on your server / firewall settings.

Comment: ok, i don't know how i can do it on azure. But the main thing is to block the request from crash the database.